# How to extract a topic from a sentence?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, nltk

I wish to tabulate all the topics from questions asked in a question paper. This is an example of the format of two questions asked in the paper:

```
question1 = 'Write short notes on the anatomy of the Circle of Willis including normal variants.'
question2 = 'Write short notes on the anatomy of the axis (C2 vertebra).'
```

From the above questions, I expect to get the topics:

```
topic1 = 'Circle of Willis including normal variants'
topic2 = 'axis (C2 vertebra)'
```

For the above, I wrote the following code snippet:

```
def extract_topic(message):
    message = re.search('Write short notes on the anatomy of the (.+?).', message)
    if message:
        return message.group(1)
```

Of course, the above code failed miserably! What am I to do? What's the easiest way to do the above? Would using NLTK make the above easy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your regex just has one mistake, you forgot to escape `.` at the end, since `.` means match any char except line break. Also `(.+?)` is non greedy, therefore it matches one char and `.` after that matches one more char.

Below code should work,

```
def extract_topic(message):
message = re.search('Write short notes on the anatomy of the (.+?)\.', message)
if message:
    return message.group(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, however, there are texts and blank spaces between the questions which return None. How do I prevent this?

Comment: It would be great if you could provide some sample input.

Comment: Like this: 

1    Write short notes on the anatomy of the Circle of Willis including normal variants.

2    Write short notes on the anatomy of the axis (C2 vertebra).

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```
def extract_topic(message):
    message = re.search('Write short notes on the anatomy of the (.*).', message)
    if message:
        return message.group(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, however, there are texts and blank spaces between the questions which return None. How do I prevent this?

Comment: I didn't quite understand your issue. Can you give an example?

Comment: Like this: 

1    Write short notes on the anatomy of the Circle of Willis including normal variants.

2    Write short notes on the anatomy of the axis (C2 vertebra).

Comment: I tried the questions, and there were no errors. Could you be more specific? Give an input, your output and expected output.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to write it in the comments as all formatting is lost, but I figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the format of your data is still the same as you show -> quite easy solution is:

```
question1 = 'Write short notes on the anatomy of the Circle of Willis including normal variants.'
question2 = 'Write short notes on the anatomy of the axis (C2 vertebra).'

list_of_questions = [question1, question2]

topics = [question.split("Write short notes on the anatomy of the ")[1] for question in list_of_questions]

print(topics)
```